# Why rax is set to -ENOSYS before TRACE_IRQS_OFF

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64

See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.21/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L168.

1. Why does RAX have to change?
2. Why is -ENOSYS chosen?

Copied from the above link:

```
ENTRY(entry_SYSCALL_64)
    UNWIND_HINT_EMPTY
    /*
     * Interrupts are off on entry.
     * We do not frame this tiny irq-off block with TRACE_IRQS_OFF/ON,
     * it is too small to ever cause noticeable irq latency.
     */

    swapgs
    /* tss.sp2 is scratch space. */
    movq    %rsp, PER_CPU_VAR(cpu_tss_rw + TSS_sp2)
    SWITCH_TO_KERNEL_CR3 scratch_reg=%rsp
    movq    PER_CPU_VAR(cpu_current_top_of_stack), %rsp

    /* Construct struct pt_regs on stack */
    pushq   $__USER_DS              /* pt_regs->ss */
    pushq   PER_CPU_VAR(cpu_tss_rw + TSS_sp2)   /* pt_regs->sp */
    pushq   %r11                    /* pt_regs->flags */
    pushq   $__USER_CS              /* pt_regs->cs */
    pushq   %rcx                    /* pt_regs->ip */
GLOBAL(entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe)
    pushq   %rax                    /* pt_regs->orig_ax */

    PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS rax=$-ENOSYS

    TRACE_IRQS_OFF
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The invocation of `PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS` doesn't change RAX. In fact it's one of the few general purpose registers that's not cleared (set to 0) by the macro.  Since RAX holds the system call number of the system call being invoked, it's value is left unchanged.  Immediately after the code you've shown it's passed as the first argument to `do_syscall_64`.

What does get set to `-ENOSYS` is the saved value of RAX on the stack.  That is, instead of saving the actual value of RAX, the macro saves `-ENOSYS`.  When the system call returns the value in RAX will be set to `-ENOSYS` unless `do_syscall_64` changes it to something else.  This presumably done so if the incoming RAX value isn't a valid system call number, `do_syscall_64` can simply return and the outgoing RAX will be `-ENOSYS` indicating that the system call is invalid.